# Detect changes on disabled field

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

It seems propertychange events are ignored while a field is in the disabled state. Is there a way to run code when the value changes?

```
<input id="country" onpropertychange="alert(country.value)" disabled="disabled"/>
<input type="button" onclick="country.value='USA'" value="Go" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you not just add in your event inside the button's onclick attribute after `country.value='USA'`? For example:

```
<input id="country" disabled="disabled" />
<input type="button" onclick="country.value='USA'; alert(country.value)" value="Go" />
```

Comment: Normally yes, but in my case no. The click handler is third-party code that I can't touch. I can add a second click hander but there's no guarantee which one will be called first. Is there an event which fires after click? 'Clicked' perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is!  In short, you'll need to fire the propertychange event yourself when the disabled is set, and to do that you'll need to change the getters and setters on the elements that you want to enable/disable.

Here are a couple of good articles about this technique:

- [MSDN getter/setter article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd229916%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)
- [MSDN getter/setter examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dd548687%28v=vs.94%29.aspx)

Unfortunately you can't just use the native fireEvent on a disabled event within the setter, because it obeys the disabled state.  Therefore we need an external event triggering system.  Luckily for us the good folks at jQuery have already done that!

So, with that knowledge I wrote a [fireOnDisable](https://gist.github.com/cmcnulty/7036509) jQuery plugin.  To use it, simply apply it to the selector eg:

```
$('#disabled_thing').fireOnDisable();
```

If you are in a browser that doesn't natively support propertychange events, this plugin will do nothing.  It's exclusively for IE8-10.  For non-IE browsers (and IE-11) use [MutationObservers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).  For IE7 or lesser, you're screwed, because they don't expose the setter/getter functions.